# What is the difference between using drupal_goto('$path') and header('Location: $path')?

Tags: 7, redirection, views

I've been struggling a lot with a `drupal_goto()` not redirecting from a view to correct path in all displays.

This is the snippet code.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_render().
 */
function HOOK_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  //if only on node matches, redirects to that node 
  if ( $view->name == 'FOO' && $view->current_display == 'BAR' && count($view->result)==1 ){
    if(is_numeric($view->result[0]->nid)){
      drupal_goto('node/' . $view->result[0]->nid);
    } 
  }
}
```

Instead, `header('Location:node/' . $view->result[0]->nid);` is working in any case. 
Why doesn't `drupal_goto()` work, sometimes?

Comment: Do you have `destination` parameter in query?


You can take a look into `drupal_goto()` and find that it uses `header('Location...` too.

Comment: @kala4ek, thank you. Indeed this is exactly what I explained in my answer :). I posted it to share experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an exposed filter with identifier named *destination*. Since [`drupal_goto()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7.x) takes care of the *destination* parameter sent in URL with the following code, it was overwriting my code.

```
  // A destination in $_GET always overrides the function arguments.
  // We do not allow absolute URLs to be passed via $_GET, as this can be an attack vector.
  if (isset($_GET['destination']) && !url_is_external($_GET['destination'])) {
    $destination = drupal_parse_url($_GET['destination']);
    $path = $destination['path'];
    $options['query'] = $destination['query'];
    $options['fragment'] = $destination['fragment'];
  }
```

Comment: I feel too stupid but I share it here, who knows, it could be helpful. Credits once again to @Clive